# why extension better-comment not working?

Tags: vscode-extensions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUHFb.png

why my better comment single comment not working , just muti-line working?

I have check the setting all i can change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself.

It turns out that better-comment only work on .js files.

For .html files, you need to use muti-line comment to make it work.